# How to describe input model as much as possible using Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an example input model as follows:

```
public class CarInputModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

This values will come from UI, what kind of annotations can I use with swagger to describe this API model as much as possible?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging help center article on how to correctly use tags and why you shouldn't force tags into question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use many annotations at all to describe the model. You mostly describe the API itself

- `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` for the http attributes
- `[Produces(typeof(CarInputModel)]` for the return type of an action and `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CarInputModel), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]` for result types based on http code (i.e. return different model on error)
- `[Route]` for the route itself

Additionally you can use Xml Docs to describe the classes and their parameters.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds a new car model.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The model to add</param>
/// <response code="201">Returns when the car was added successfully and returns the location to the new resource</response>
/// <response code="400">Invalid Request data.</response>
/// <response code="409">Car mode already exists.</response>
/// <returns>The newly added model on success and a list of errors on failure.</returns>
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CarInputModel), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SerializableError), (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict)]
public IActionResult AddCar(CarInputModel model) 
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Represents a car
/// </summary>
public class CarInputModel {
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the car
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Model of the car
    /// </summary>
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

In order to use XmlDocs you need to enable compilation of the xml docs in your project settings (and the of your models) and then add this to your Startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    var appEnv = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath, $"{appEnv.ApplicationName}.xml"));
});
```